# Semaphore with queue

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

```
public class SemaphoreWithQueues  implements Semaphore {
    private List<Object> queue;
    private AtomicInteger current = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private int permits;

    public SemaphoreWithQueues(int permits) {
        this.permits = permits;
        this.queue = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<>());
    }

    @Override
    public void enter() throws InterruptedException {
        if (current.get() < permits) {
           current.incrementAndGet();
        } else {
            Object block = new Object();
            synchronized (block) {
                queue.add(block);
                block.wait();
                current.incrementAndGet();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void leave() {
        if(queue.size() != 0) {
            Object block = queue.get(0);
            queue.remove(0);
            synchronized (block) {
                block.notify(); //Unblock quenue
            }
        }
        current.decrementAndGet();
        //current lessen and current thread have time come in block if(...)
        // in enter() faster then another thread increased current
    }
}

> The program usually output: 
> 
> 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2

**Where run() of both threads is almost the same, such as:**


     public void run(){
                for (int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
                    try {
                        semaphore.enter();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.err.println(e);
                    }
                    System.out.println(2);
                    semaphore.leave();

                }
            }
```

There are 2 threads using this semaphore. When 1 thread increases the **queue**, the second is waiting, the problem is that if we extracted the object from **quene** and unblocked it, then the thread that finished **leave()** start **enter()** faster and again increments the **counter**, while the awaked thread also increments the **counter**, **current = 2**, and the list is empty.

**SORRY FOR BAD ENGLISH**

Comment: ` if (current < permits) {
            current++;
        }` is not an atomic operation.

Comment: I changed the int to AtomicInteger in the current, but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: `AtomicInteger` wouldn't help, since another thread could change `current` between the comparison `current < permits` and changing `current`.

Comment: Wots wrong with 'java.util.concurrent.Semaphore' ?

Comment: @Jochen Bedersdorfer How do I can to fix this?

Comment: Use one of the existing Semaphore/BlockingQueue implementations is your best bet. Unless you are doing something unusual, java.util.concurrent should have everything you need

Comment: methods enter and leave should be synchronized

Comment: Realization of semaphore is my Task in school

Comment: If methods will have synhronize, I can't create quene

Comment: Why? What's wrong with synchronizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems in the code.

1. Synchronization: Synchronization should be done for a shareable
   resource. Why it is done for a local object which has scope only for
   that method.

> Object block = new Object();
>               synchronized (block) {

2. Both current and queue are independent properties, they should be
   synchronized together.

Now let's come to point If you really want to create a semaphore using Queue. You do not need all this logic. You can use existing Java class e.g. BlockingQueue. Here is the implementation

```
class SemaphoreWithQueues implements Semaphore{
private BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

public SemaphoreWithQueues(int permits) {
    if(queue == null){
        queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(permits);
    }
}

public void enter() {
    queue.offer(1);
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " got a permit.");
}

public void leave() throws InterruptedException {
    queue.take();
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " left the permit.");
}
}
```

And Task to use the semaphore

```
class Task implements Runnable {
private SemaphoreWithQueues semaphore;
public Task(SemaphoreWithQueues semaphore){
    this.semaphore = semaphore;
}

public void run(){
    for (int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
        semaphore.enter();
        try {
            semaphore.leave();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

}
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SemaphoreWithQueues semaphoreWithQueues = new SemaphoreWithQueues(5);
    Thread th1 = new Thread(new Task(semaphoreWithQueues));
    Thread th2 = new Thread(new Task(semaphoreWithQueues));
    Thread th3 = new Thread(new Task(semaphoreWithQueues));
    th1.start();
    th2.start();
    th3.start();
}

}
```

But personally I do not like using Queue to create Semaphores, as it wastes memory unnecessary by creating elements in queue. Despite of this you can create a semaphore using single shareable object with permits using wait and notify mechanism. You can try with this approach. If you would like.